# Oracle XMLType internal format

Tags: xml, oracle, unicode, utf-8, xmltype

I have an Oracle 10g 2 database created with no Unicode support (NLS_CHARACTERSET defines a single-byte encoding). How does XMLType handle internal text data in such a case - as single-byte strings or as multi-byte strings? Will I get data loss loading UTF-8/UTF-16 encoded XML file from a BFILE into an XMLType column of a table that belongs to a single-byte database?